# How to show assigned user roles in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I am learning ASP.NET Razor Pages.  I am trying to learn Authorization process by making a simple web application with Users and Roles that have different levels of access .

I could make Users and Roles via Identity management in ASP.NET ( Razor Pages ), and also I could manage to assign Roles to Users ( SQL table below) and everything works fine in terms of authentication and authorization.  Now I am trying to show users and their roles in Index page of Role Assignment folder , but cant find out  where I can find a collection of user-role.
In the code below, I have made custom User identity LearLogin4 and am able to retrieve Users and Roles but where is the connection that shows John is Admin and Jane is accountant ?

```
namespace LearLogin4.Pages.RolesManager
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager<LearLogin4User> _userManager;

        public IndexModel(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<LearLogin4User> userManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public IList<IdentityRole> Roles { get;set; } = default!;
        public IList<LearLogin4User> Users { get; set; } = default!;



        public Task<IList<string>> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Users= await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
            Roles = await _roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
     
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like the linking table between user and roles.  Those columns would usually contain primary keys.  (It's a many to many mapping...)

Comment: @pcalkins   actually it is, i just cant figure out what is the best way to extract data?  I thought I should run a Linq and connect each user-id to role-id, and then run loops to relate them but that sounds like a messy job, I think there must be a better way ?

Comment: You could loop... just get all the users, and check the linking table for the keys, and get the corresponding roles.  Or use a Linq query:  something like: Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role).ToList(); maybe.

Comment: @pcalkins  that sounds like my answer,  would you make it more like the code and post as answer that i can mark it ?

Comment: You can go ahead and do that.  (You are allowed to answer your own questions here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display which user has which role on your Index pageyou could use `UserManager` service which has method called `GetRolesAsync()`.What you'll need to do is create a loop in your code that goes through each user, asks `UserManager` what roles they have, and then saves that info somewhere you can show it on your page.
I suggest making a little class to hold the username and their roles together. Let's call it `UserRoleViewModel`. Then, you collect all this information into a list during your page's `OnGetAsync()` method. Once you have this list ready, after that you will just need to display it on your Index page. You can make a simple table in your Razor page that lists users in one column and their roles in another.

First, define a class to hold the user-role information:

```
public class UserRoleViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your `OnGetAsync()` method, create a list of this class and populate it:

```
public IList<UserRoleViewModel> UserRoles { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    Users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
    Roles = await _roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
    UserRoles = new List<UserRoleViewModel>();

    foreach (var user in Users)
    {
        var rolesForUser = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        UserRoles.Add(new UserRoleViewModel
        {
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Roles = rolesForUser
        });
    }
}
```

Last step to display this information in your Razor page, you could use a table like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Roles</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var userRole in Model.UserRoles)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@userRole.UserName</td>
            <td>@string.Join(", ", userRole.Roles)</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.net core there are identity model that you can use for your project security and get the users their specified claim.

in Identity model we have items below for controlling the security for our project: User, Role, UserClaim, UserToken, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserRole.
each of the items mentioned represents an item related to identity of the user.
according to your tables shown in picture you have to combine data in related tables to find your favorite data, for example there is a standard Microsoft table named AspnetRoles which has your system roles in string format like ADMIN or Accountant or something else.

if you want to make an identity system for your project in web service you can make report web services based on requested input, for example if you want to make a web service for getting list of all of roles in your system you should make a select query on AspnetRoles and for other items like this way.

I hope this comment help you